# How to run function 10 times while it is not true and exit from script

Tags: bash

I have a function named `ping_test` for testing if a machine is responding to ping:

```
function ping_test() { 
    ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
        echo "Machine is online"
        return 0         
    else    
        echo "Machine is offline"
        return 1
    fi  

}

other_function1
other_function2
while ! ping_test; do
ping_test
done
other_function3
other_function4
exit 0
```

How can I exit the script (not execute functions `other_function3` and `other_function4`) after 10 times of ping failure?

Comment: Naming a function `test` is asking for trouble with the `test` shell built-in or command.

Comment: There's also a stray `done` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Try it 10 times, and break if it succeeds early.

```
other_function1
other_function2

for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
    test && break
done || {
    echo "Pings failed"
    exit 1
}

other_function3
other_function4
```

The exit status of the `for` loop itself will tell you if the loop ended naturally (non-zero) or due to a `break` following a successful test (zero).

Comment: Not working:the for loop ends without echo "Pings failed" after 10 tries...

Comment: Works as expected for me. Are you sure your `test` function is correctly returning 1 on a ping failure?

Answer (score 0):

My `ping` (macOS) has built-in functionality to support your use case:

```
ping -c 10 -o xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where `-c count` is for

> Stop after sending (and receiving) *`count`* `ECHO_RESPONSE` packets

and `-o` is

> Exit successfully after receiving one reply packet.

This means, your code could look like this:

```
pingtest() {
    if ping -c 10 -o xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; then
        echo "Machine is online"
    else
        echo "Machine is offline"
        exit 1
    fi
}

other_function1
other_function2
pingtest
other_function3
other_function4
```

and the whole retry mechanism is handled by `ping` itself.

Notice that `test` isn't the best name for your function: it's usually already a shell built-in and the name of a binary in your `$PATH`.